# Changing a MySQL database retrospectively

Tags: mysql, version-control

Is there a method to track changes to a MySQL database? I develop offline and then commit all the changes to my server. For the app itself I use Git and it works nicely.

However, for the database, I'm changing everything manually because the live database contains customer data and I cannot just replace it with the development database.

Is there a way to only have the structural changes applied without completely replacing one db with another?

Comment: If you find one I'd love to hear about it, so far only method has involved committing the alter scripts to source control.  You have the problem that if you roll back/forwards a database there can be data loss/corruption issues due to field changes.  I've yet to find a system that handles this to my satisfaction for MySQL however I can't help thinking there's got to be one somewhere.

Answer (score 0):

The term you're looking for is 'database migrations' (and no, it doesn't refer to moving from one RDBMS to another). Migrations are a way to programatically version control your database structure. Most languages have some kind of migrations toolkit, often as part of an ORM library/framework.

For PHP you can look at [Doctrine](http://www.doctrine-project.org/documentation/manual/1_0/zh/migrations)

For Ruby it's [Rails](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/migrations.html) of course

Answer (score 0):

The key to have keep track of your changes is [Snapshots](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Snapshot_%28computer_storage%29) my friend.

Now, it's a wide field. The first thing you have to do is decide if you want to keep track of your database with some kind of data in it. If that's the case you have several options, from using [LVM](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Logical_volume_management), [copying InnoDB binary logs](http://www.mysqlperformanceblog.com/2012/01/18/backing-up-binary-log-files-with-mysqlbinlog/), and the simple [mysqldump](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/mysqldump.html).

Now, if what you wanna do is have some smooth transition between your database changes (i mean, you added a column, for example), you have some other options.

The first one is replication. That's a great option, but is a little complex. With replication you may alter one slave and after it's done, with some locking, you can make it master, and replace master, and so on. It's really difficult, but is the better option.

If you cannot afford replication, what you must do is apply the changes to your single-master DB with the minimum downtime. Some good option is this:

Suppose you want to replace your Customer table to add a "facebook_account" field. First, you can use an alias table, like this:

The original table (it has data):

```
CREATE TABLE `customer` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `name` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB;
```

The new one:

```
CREATE TABLE `new_customer` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `name` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `facebook_account` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB;
```

Or simply:

```
CREATE TABLE new_customer LIKE customer;
ALTER TABLE new_customer add column facebook_account VARCHAR(255);
```

Now we're gonna copy the data to the new table. We'll need to issue some other things first, i'll explain them each at a time.

First, you can allow other connections to modify the customer table while your making the change of table, so i'll issue a lock. If you want to learn more about this go [here](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/lock-tables.html):

```
LOCK TABLES customer WRITE ,new_customer WRITE;
```

Now i flush the table to write any cache content to the filesystem:

```
FLUSH TABLES customer;
```

Now we can do the insert. First I disable the keys for performance issues. After the data is inserted i enable the keys again.

```
ALTER TABLE new_customer DISABLE KEYS;
INSERT INTO new_customer(id,name,facebook_account) SELECT customer.id,customer.name, Null FROM customer;
ALTER TABLE new_customer ENABLE KEYS;
```

Now we can switch the tables.

```
ALTER TABLE customer RENAME old_customer;
ALTER TABLE new_customer RENAME customer;
```

Finally we have to release the lock.

```
UNLOCK TABLES;
```

That's it. If you want to keep track of your modified tables you may want to rename your old_customer table, to something else or move it to other database.

The only issue i didn't cover here is about Triggers. You have to pay atention to any enabled trigger, but it will depend on your schema.

That's it, hope it helps.